# Apache Derby: Achieving 'SELECT INTO' behaviour

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

It is possible in MS SQL Server to store the results of query into a table, and most importantly, have the query create the table:

```
SELECT an_existing_column
INTO table_xyz
FROM an_existing_table
```

This is also possible in MySQL using:

```
CREATE TABLE table_xyz
SELECT an_existing_column
FROM an_existing_table
```

I have searched the [Apache Derby Reference Guide](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/) and cannot see a method for achieving similar behaviour.

Does anyone know if this possible in Apache Derby?

Comment: the `create table as select ...` is standard ANSI SQL. The `select .. into ... ` is specific to SQL Server.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, ta. I started out with Sybase and SQL Server. Clearly learning non-standard extensions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store the results of a query into a table:

```
INSERT INTO table_xyz (an_existing_column) SELECT an_existing_column FROM an_existing_table;
```

Create a table from another table:

All Columns:

```
CREATE TABLE table_xyz AS SELECT * FROM an_existing_table WITH NO DATA;
```

Specific Column:

```
CREATE TABLE table_xyz AS SELECT an_existing_column FROM an_existing_table WITH NO DATA;
```

Comment: Excellent, this seems to work. Thank you. Strangely, I cannot find the `WITH NO DATA` clause in the reference guide (yet). +1

Comment: @hmjd [Here](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/ref/rrefsqlj24513.html) you can find at least a bit of explanation under the `CREATE TABLE ... AS ... ` caption.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work in JAVA DB, the correct way to do it is:

For all columns:

Step 1: Create a new table with a different name. for example, *my_new_table*:

```
CREATE TABLE my_new_table AS SELECT * FROM original_table WITH NO DATA;
```

This statement creates a new table from original table in the same format and no data copied. It is required to specify `WITH NO DATA` for it creates a new table with the same columns.

Step 2: Copy data from *orig_table* to *my_new_table* using `INSERT INTO`.

```
INSERT INTO my_new_table  SELECT * FROM orig_table.
```

Then you will have all the data copied.

Comment: Shouldn't it be step 2: INSERT INTO my_new_table   SELECT * FROM orig_table